# Опция --check-links в bsdtar

Tags: tar

Всем привет.Прочитал страницу руководства по bsdtar. Разобрался во всем, кроме опции --check-links. Буду очень благодарен, если Вы мне объясните в каких случаях она необходима. Если не затруднит, то с примером использования пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно описанию опция --check-links делает следующее:

> If this option was given, tar will check the number of links dumped for each processed file. If this number does not match the total number of hard links for the file, a warning message will be output (6).

Когда tar осуществляет архивацию, для каждой жесткой ссылки записывается блок именующий файл, на который указывает ссылка. Это делается для того, чтобы не дублировать содержимое архива.

Опция --check-links выдаст предупреждение в том случае, когда количество ссылок на файл записанных утилитой не совпадает с количеством ссылок на файл в файловой системе. Например, если есть некий файл и есть жесткие ссылки на него, то в случае, когда осуществляется архивация этого и только этого файла, будет выдано предупреждение, поскольку не будут учтены ссылки.